# Does anyone use diamond files to touch up/sharpen circular saw blades?

Tags: tools, cutting, sharpening

I am  tooling up to sharpen circular saw  blades, besides purchasing a  good power  machine I wanted to purchase some quality  diamond files for  touch-up and perhaps even sharpening the entire  blade, I use diamond files/stones/wheels all  the  time  for  other  tasks, so  I was surprised I  couldn't  find  much in  the  way  of good files.

Is  anyone using  diamond files for  working  on  their circular blades?  I haven't found much  information on the  use  of diamond  files for  circular saws, so I wanted to see if others here were using them.

Thanks
sunaj

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests purchasing recommendations/brand recommendations

Comment: Welcome to Woodworking.SE! Unfortunately, purchasing recommendations are off-topic for this site, but if you remove the part inquiring about what brand of files, we will be happy to reopen.

Comment: Diamond *files* wouldn't normally be used for this kind of work because they're A) a little coarse and B) not available in known grit numbers (at least not that I've seen). It's more common to use small versions of the diamond honing plates instead, often what are called paddles because they have a long plastic base with the diamond plate mounted at one end. However, there's no reason you can't use a full-size diamond plate for sharpening circular saw blades, a bit cumbersome perhaps but the extra width or length shouldn't get in the way.

Comment: @rob: This really shouldn't be voted to close.  He is both asking if this is a best known methods and if so asking for which particular file would work best.

Comment: Ok I  edited  it as  requested

Comment: @jbord39 The first part is definitely on-topic, but we try to avoid brand recommendations for various reasons, not the least of which are that they can often be opinion-based, solicit "me too" answers, and have integrity implications for the site.

Comment: @rob: sometimes using a brand is opinion based (both products on par with equality or some pro's/con's for each).  sometimes it is not (just a crappy product).

Comment: @jbord39 we are in agreement on that point. That said, as a blanket policy, brand recommendations are off-topic for the site as outlined in https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and for the other reasons I mentioned above. If you would like to discuss further, please feel free to open a question on meta.

Comment: I use a diamond disc off of eBay for my router. It works pretty well but you need to know what your doing when sharpening. Otherwise it will not turn out. I like to work from the top of the tooth.

Answer (score 2):

Mattias Wandel from Woodgears.ca has a good method for sharpening circular saw blades with a diamond disc in a drill/dremel. He goes a lot more in depth and builds a jig to do this, but you could do the same thing by hand with a little less precision.

https://woodgears.ca/table_saw/sharpening_jig.html